# How to get UTxO transaction id using cardano-serialization-lib

Tags: transaction, nami-wallet, cardano-serialization-lib, bech32

I'm missing transaction prefix in order to get bech32 hash of transaction id using cardano-serialization-lib.

What prefix is used in transaction bech32 hash and how can I find/compute one?

```
const decodeUtxo =
  (wasm: WasmT) =>
  (encodedUtxo: string): WasmNamespace.TransactionUnspentOutput =>
    wasm.TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(Buffer.from(encodedUtxo, "hex"));

const collateralUtxos = (await wallet.getCollateral()).map(decodeUtxo(wasm));

const prefix = '' // how can I find this?

// to_bech32 function requires prefix
const collateralTxHashes = collateralUtxos.map((utxo) => utxo.input().transaction_id().to_bech32(prefix))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get transaction id using cardano-serialization-lib you should convert transaction id to bytes and convert them to hex string.

```
Buffer.from(utxo.input().transaction_id().to_bytes()).toString('hex')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: utxo.input().transaction_id()

Comment: Close enough. Only thing left is to load bytes into Buffer and convert it to hex string.